# Accurate placement of SVG images in TCPDF

Tags: pdf, svg, tcpdf

I need to create a PDF document where I can place SVG images with millimeter accuracy. I am using TCPDF for this purpose.  I am a relative newbie to TCPDF and have run into several strange issues

Here is my test SVG image

```
<svg width="90mm" height="60mm"  viewBox='0 0 90 60'    
 preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <rect width='90' height='60' style='fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-
  width:1'/>
</svg>
```

and here are my test TCPDF generation instructions

```
<?php
 require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
 $pdf = new TCPDF("P","mm","A4",true,'UTF-8',false);
 $pdf->setImageScale(1);
 $pdf->SetMargins(15,28.5,15,true);
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->ImageSVG('images/colorbox.svg',0,0,'','','','',0,true);
 //frame just for testing
 $pdf->Output('colorbox.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

**What I expect to get**

- A blue square
- 90mm wide & 60mm high
- Placed 15mm from the left hand edge of the paper & 28.5mm down from the top

**What I get instead**

- A blue square - good so far
- A frame that is the right size: 90 x 60 mm
- Placed **17mm** from the left hand edge of the paper and **0mm** from the top edge of the paper.

I did my printing tests of of Firefox having ensured that the "Shrink to fit page width" option was turned off.

From what I can see

- The top margin instruction is just being ignored
- I have a mysterious horizointal offset of 2mm
- Although the 90 x 60 instruction appears to have been understood and applied to the containing frame, the actual blue rectangle is a whole lot smaller.

Either TCPDF has only an imperfect understanding of millimbeter units in SVG or else my own understanding of how to control TCPDF is flawed.

---

I have found that the spurious +2mm margin is a Firefox issue.  Print fidelity turns out to be the best with IE11 - surprise, surprise, I never thought I would ever say anything good about IE, ever.

The frame size is picture perfect - 90mm x 60mm just as instructed.  The blue SVG rectangle is printed at 32 x 21mm, i.e. a strange reduction to 35% of the desired size.  I am not the best of authorities when it comes to CSS print measurement units but if I recall correctly 1pt is 0.35mm.  So TCPDF is treating my SVG graphic - which explicitly specifies mm - as having dimensions in points?

Comment: SVG is case sensitive so it's viewBox and not viewbox. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the case sensitivity issue Robert.  However, no that does not make any difference here. The top margin setting is still being ignored, the frame is being drawn to the right size but its contents - the blue rectangle - are still incorrectly sized.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where an A4 SVG was not filling an A4 PDF - it was strangely zoomed in and cropped at the edges for some reason.

I shrunk the SVG file to be much smaller than the page (A6), then I was able to scale it back up to be exactly the right size using TCPDF:

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file, 0, 0, 297, 210);
```